# FPDI (TCPDF) fseek(): stream does not support seeking

Tags: php, html, tcpdf, fpdf, fpdi

I'm using `TCPDF` and `FPDI` to embed an existing pdf file into my new pdf generated with database data.  The problem is when I charge the page, it throws this error:

> *Severity: Warning*
>
> Message: fseek(): stream does not support seeking
>
> Filename: fpdi/pdf_parser.php
>
> Type: Exception
>
> Message: Unable to find xref table.

**Help please!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message sais FPDI requires the opened stream to be seekable.

If the PDF is not available you may pass it to an appropriate stream wrapper. [Here](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/miscellaneous/using-a-pdf-from-a-php-variable-instead-of-a-file/#question-76) you find a stream wrapper for variables, which may help you.